# Resumable Download with Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to apply **resumable donload with gmail API**, getting an Message, following these principles: https://google-developers.appspot.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download [1]

However, I don't find a method of Getting message thorugh that use MediaHttpDownloader,in a similar way that insert method message, has one with MediaHttpUploader:

So, I'm trying to get a message without service-specific generated libraries, following this example for Drive [1].

Instead of using:

```
DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new        CustomProgressListener());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

In drive you must use:

```
MediaHttpDownloader downloader = new MediaHttpDownloader(transport, httpRequestInitializer);
downloader.setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
downloader.download(requestUrl, out);
```

In Gmail API get message method, request URL is: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{ID_MESSAGE}?format=raw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I get YOUR_API_KEY from Google Credential method, getAccessToken().

I try this code, but I think I have problems with OutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HttpTransport transportHttp = new UrlFetchTransport();
String request = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/"+idMensaje+"?format=raw&fields=raw&key="+key;
GenericUrl genericURL = new GenericUrl(request);


        MediaHttpDownloader downloader = new MediaHttpDownloader(transportHttp, serviceUserGmail.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
        downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
        downloader.setChunkSize(1024 * 1024);
        downloader.download(genericURL, out);
```

I get this error:

com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400
Unsupported Output Format
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1054)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:245)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:199)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:156)

How I must define outputStream out? (if this is the error?

Thanks.